# Find the present value of 300 pounds paid every 3 years

Tags: finance

Using an interest rate of 7% per annum, ﬁnd the present value of ﬁfteen payments of
amount £300 each payable every three years, with the ﬁrst payment made at the end of
the second year

I thought this as equal to an annuity of 100 pounds payable in arrears r for 45 years discounted back by v^1 at 7% because it is starting at the end of year 2. but I get the wrong answer as it should be 1358.48. Can someone explain me why my method is wrong?

Comment: $\dfrac{300}{1.07^2} \times \dfrac{1-1.07^{-3 \times 15}}{ 1-1.07^{-3}} \approx 1358.478469$

Comment: What formula is that?

Comment: [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)

Comment: And would you mind explaining why my method is wrong?

Comment: You have not said what answer you found initially

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_t$ denote the payment at future time $t$. Then the future payments are
$p_2,p_5,\dots,p_{44}$, or $p_{2+3k}$ where $k=0,1,\dots 14$. The present
value of $p_{2+3k}$ is $\frac{300}{(1+0.07)^{2+3k}}$, hence the
present value of the entire cashflow is
$$300\times\sum_{k=0}^{14}(1.07)^{-2-3k}=1358.48$$

Comment: Can you explain me why my method is wrong tho?

Comment: Your method is wrong because delayed periodic instalments of 300 is NOT the same as 100 paid for 45 years in arrears.

Comment: If it wasn't delayed, would my method have been correct?